# Excel file still open when console application running

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I have a console application that takes a web service response and outputs the properties to a excel file using closedxml. Whenever I create the excel file, if the console application is still running it won't let me open the file. I'm not sure where I am going wrong as I do have a using for the method that creates the excel file. Could another part of the code be holding the file open? I have added the excel create method.

```
static readonly XLWorkbook wbook = new XLWorkbook();

public void ExcelCreate(FixedCall[] fix, string fileName)
        {
            using (wbook)
            {
                int col = 1;
                var ws = wbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
                foreach (var propertyInfo in from propertyInfo in typeof(FixedCall).GetProperties()
                                             where !propertyInfo.Name.Contains("ExtensionData")
                                             select propertyInfo)
                {
                    int row = 1;
                    ws.Cell(row++, col).Value = propertyInfo.Name;

                    for (int i = 0; i < fix.Length; i++)
                    {
                        ws.Cell(row++, col).Value = propertyInfo.GetValue(fix[i]);
                    }

                    col++;
                }

                wbook.SaveAs(File.Create(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), $"{fileName}.xlsx")));
            }
        }
```

Comment: although you used using, it is not 'using' since it is a static object. close the wbook in using.

Comment: I have tried adding wbook.Dispose(); in the using statement but it has not made any difference.

Comment: I am not very familiar with C# but you are declaring wbook as `readonly` … and then trying to modify it using `Workheets.Add()`…

Comment: Maybe try putting the Workbook inside the function and not making it static. Because you have it at global scope it won’t get released until the program finishes.

Comment: @DS_London tried adding the XLWorkbook wbook = new XLWorkbook() within the function same issue.

Comment: @DS_London https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly - readonly doesn't make the field contents read only

Comment: Have you tried `wbook.Close()` as suggested by @urlreader above?

Comment: I'd do `using (var wbook = new XLWorkbook())` and delete the static line entirely

Comment: @DS_London wbook does not contain a method for Close. You also mentioned adding the object locally. This appears to have worked. It did not last night unsure why but thank you.

Comment: @CaiusJard This appears to have resolved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: I stand corrected it's strange it appeared to work but when I closed the application and opened it again, I experienced the same issue.

Comment: I'm not really sure what that means. Is this absolutely the only place in the entire console application that you ever make reference to an XLWorkBook? The code you have follows the main example in the github readme quite closely, now that it uses `using(var ...)`

Comment: @DS_London I think that's the wrong doc.. https://closedxml.github.io/ClosedXML/ is the lib in use, and it probably apes some other lib closely to provide an easy transition for devs who already have code in that other lib, to just change references and have most stuff work similarly (for example Excel Interop and EPPlus are nearly the same usage patterns)

Comment: @CaiusJard I am indebted once again.

Comment: You can probably also shorten `wbook.SaveAs(File.Create(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), $"{fileName}.xlsx")));` to `wbook.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), $"{fileName}.xlsx"));` whether it will make a diff to just pass the filename and make it CXML's problem to close the file I don't know.. The answer would likely be in https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML/Excel/XLWorkbook.cs but I'm  a bit short on time to look through it to check what happens to any stream/writer you pass it

Comment: @CaiusJard `wbook.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), $"{fileName}.xlsx"));` this was the issue. I'm guessing the File.Create was conflicting with ClosedXml. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a pattern of:

```
using(var wbook = new XLWorkBook()){

  ...
  var fullPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), $"{fileName}.xlsx");
  wbook.SaveAs(fullPath);
}
```

By providing just the file path, you aren't making yourself potentially responsible for closing/disposing a file stream; it's handed off to ClosedXml and I'm sure they will tidy up during the dispose if not before..

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused by

`wbook.SaveAs(File.Create(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), $"{fileName}.xlsx")));`

Changing to:
 `wbook.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), $"{fileName}.xlsx"));`

Also removing the static field and adding as part of the using block  `using (var wbook = new XLWorkbook())` resolved the problem.

There appeared to be a conflict between File and ClosedXml on what was handling the excel doc.